# JavaScript - Is there a way how to draw SVG path UNDER the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, jquery-svg

I need a path that goes UNDER the content (text) - is there a way how to do that?

(as already been answered somewhere else, z-index doesnt affect svg paths)

Comment: Declare text after path declaration

Comment: Not possible - paths are created by user-interaction (connecting two elements) - so text has to by there before that

Comment: You say z-Index doesnt affect, but if you declare paths and text in different svg layers z-index will be work

Comment: Its the SVG z-idnex VS HTML z-index problem I found out :) thanks for the solution :) (you actually solved two of my questions at the same time x) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `PATH` and `TEXT` in different `SVG` layers, and put one layer onto another like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position:absolute;z-index:1">
  <text x="100" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG</text>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position:absolute;z-index:0">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJZrU/

Comment: This is very interesting solution :) I didnt even know you can just put text to SVG :)

Comment: Yes, I advise you to separate graphical part and text content as much as possible:)

Comment: The text doesn't have to be in an SVG.  You can still use HTML for that part.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/WJZrU/5/